# Resolver un error de protección de rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un sistema de rutas en laravel que protegen a los usuarios guests de entrar al admin dashboard, el problema es que solo puedo bloquear a los visitantes y no a los usuarios "normales" (Es decir los usuarios que compran cosas, los visitantes no pueden comprar).

Intente hacer un middleware que los bloquea pero no funciona bien, me gustaría saber como arreglarlo.

Esta es la ruta que quiero proteger

```
Route::get('/admin', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdmin', 
    'as' => 'admin.dashboard',
    'middleware' => 'auth', 'admin' //Es el modulo de entrar al admin, solo usuarios registrados lo pueden usar
]);
```

El middleware de auth que viene por default en Laravel solo logra proteger el dashboard de los usuarios no registrados, es decir un usuario que se registró normalmente puede entrar escribiendo la url y necesito evadir eso, pero no se como

Este es mi código de insertar usuarios, usando en UserController, por si necesitan información de este

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getSignup(){
        return view('user.signup'); //Manda al usuario al signup
    }

    public function postSignup(Request $request){ //Crear el usuario
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]); //Valida al usuario deacuerdo si es unico y su clave es mayor a 4

        $user=new User([
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),

        ]);

        $user->save(); //Salva al usuario
        Auth::login($user); //Arranca la sesion
        return redirect()->route('user.profile');
    }

    public function getSignin(){
        return view('user.signin');
    }

    public function postSignin(Request $request){ //Inicio de sesion
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]); //Valida los campos

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'type' => 'cliente'])){
          return redirect()->route('user.profile');
        } //Valida si el usuario es un cliente

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'type' => 'admin'])){
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
          } //Valida si el usuario es un admin

        return redirect()->back();
        }

    public function getProfile(){
        return view('user.profile');
    }

    public function getLogout(){
      Auth::logout();
      return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
    }
```

Este es el código que tengo en el Middleware de Authentication

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('user.signin');
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en el AdminMiddleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Redirect;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handel an Incoming request.
     * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type == 'admin')
        {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('product.index');
        }

    }
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en Kernel.php, el middleware si esta iniciado

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
}
```

Así es que como tengo la tabla de users, por alguna razon el AdminMiddleware no se comunica con ella, o no sabe como hacerlo

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'cliente',
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Esta línea esta mal por necesidad (error de sintaxis): `'middleware' => 'auth', 'admin'`, debería ser: `'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']`

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses [Spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel) y uses los roles y permissions de usuario. Por que cuando el proyecto se hace grande te puedes volver loco.

Es muy facil usar los roles en laravel y te solucionan problemas como los que describes con un simple comando.

Los pasos son bastante simples:

1. instalar y migrar Spatie/Permissions.

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider"
```

2. a cada user le asignas uno ( o mas roles)
3. para cada ruta api pides algun rol especifico.

ejemplo:

Roles:

```
class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
    {
        $role1 = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
        $role2 = Role::create(['name' => 'player']);
        
        Permission::create(['name' => 'crear'])->assignRole($role1); // asignRole si solo 1 role
        Permission::create(['name' => 'jugar'])->syncRoles([$role1,$role2]); // syncRoles si mas de 1 role        
    }
}
// por que a 'crear' pongo solo 1 role ?
// por que a 'jugar' pongo 2 roles ? 
// a quien quiero darle el permiso de 'crear' ? solo a admin
// a quien quiero darle el permiso de 'jugar' ? a admin y a player
```

Asegurate que el modelo users usa hasRoles:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles, HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
//....
// resto del modelo
//...
}
```

A partir de a aquí ya lo tienes, en cada user le asignas un role...

```
User::create([
            'name' => 'basicplayer',
            'email' => 'basic@player.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('basicplayer')
        ])->assignRole('player');

// en assignRole pones el nombre del Role i no del permiso
// en mi caso el role es player i tiene el permiso de jugar
```

Entonces en las rutas api le pides un role específico:

```
Route::post('/crearjuego', [GameCreatorController::class, 'crearGame'])->middleware('can:jugar');

Route::post('/crearQuestion', [GameCreatorController::class, 'crearQuestion'])->middleware('can:crear');

// al poner ->middleware('can:crear') solo se le permite acceder aquí a los que tengan este permiso.
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo estás teniendo en el `método handle de AdminMiddleware`.
Prueba a hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!Auth::user()->type == 'admin') {
        return redirect('product.index');
    }
}
```